# How to Get A Function Name From a Library and Address in Linux C

Tags: c, linux, dlopen

I am learning how to use the functions dlopen, dlsym, etc. to get the address of a given function within a given library, but how do I do the opposite? For example, if I know my process is currently at gtk_main+0xa7 in libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0, how can I determine what function that is?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: By reading what's before the plus sign. :D 0xa7 is a place inside gtk_main, which is, with some debugging info, translatable to a line in a source file.

Comment: You would have to convert and address (and/or offset) into a symbol. This is only possible if you've got symbols available for the code you've linked. If you're doing something that ends up with `gtk_main+0xa7`, it's likely that the symbols available don't go any deeper than that (which would be needed to get a line number). Possibly recompiling your library with the `-g` flag will result in better symbols.

Comment: You may have a look to 'nm' tool which is able to give you content of static/dynamic objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the address related to object space you can use `nm`. On my own libgtk-x11… it gives:

```
# nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.23
000000000006da20 T gtk_about_dialog_get_artists
000000000006d800 T gtk_about_dialog_get_authors
000000000006d260 T gtk_about_dialog_get_comments
…
```

Option `-D` is needed for dynamic symbols, and you should just have a look to "T" symbols (which are "really" inside the object). Of course these addresses are related to the object, not you address space in your program.

Note that you will only get starting addresses of entries, so if you get an address *inside* a function you should have to compute the nearest address. Look at `nm` manpage for other data available.

You may find where objects are mapped for a given program by looking at /proc/PID/maps, at least.